# none of the ubuntu installing in my pc

Tags: dual-boot

I have tried all windows versions from xp to win8.1 .all works fine. But when i tried installing ubuntu from 10.10 to 14.04 i am getting hardware exception like kernal panic, not in sync, like that. What can i do ? I even tried xubuntu,lubuntu,zorin,fedora,pear ect.., all fails. only fedora runs but i am unable to play any audios or videos even connected to network. all other fails even at the live cd booting itself.what can be done to make kernal in sync?

**> I am also getting machine check fatal exception,
Tsc 0 processor 0:6f2 time 1400026888 socket 0 apic 0 microcode 51 ,
run above through 'mcelog --ascii',
trying to reboot..**

hardware of my pc
1 gb ram
320 gb hard disk
intel pentium processor

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the first question is how are you installing, what medium are you using to install Ubuntu?

---

I use Unetbooting
  http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/
 to make a bootable USB stick for installation, and it has worked on several versions of ubuntu.  I am currently using Lubuntu because my computer is so old; i386 Dell Laptop.

Comment: My system wont support usb instalation since it is old. I have tried instalation using dvd only...